# Migrate SQLite dump to PostgreSQL deployed on Kubernetes

Tags: postgresql, sqlite, kubernetes

I am trying to migrate a SQLite dump to PostgreSQL deployed on Kubernetes but I am having issues connecting the dots.

I have created a SQLite dump using the following command:

`sqlite3 sqlite.db .dump > dump.sql`

Now, I want to migrate it to my Kubernetes deployment.
I have connected to it using:

`psql -h <external IP of node> -U postgresadmin --password -p <port that i got using kubectl get svc postgres>`

Everything seems to work so far, it is now I run into problems that resulted in me having two questions!

1. I have seen some question regarding migrating SQLite to PostgreSQL, and it seems this command will do that:
   `psql /path/to/psql -d database -U username -W <
   /the/path/to/dump.sql`. Will I have to create the same tables (empty but with same columns etc.) in PostgreSQL if the dump contains several tables, or will this command do this automatically? I believe I do, based on output I share in question 2, but will it also move on automatically to the next table?
2. How do I combine the command in question 1 to migrate it to the kubernetes deployment? I tried with adding `< dump.sql` to the command I used connecting to it but got the following output:

```
CREATE TABLE
INSERT 0 1
ERROR:  relation "first_report" does not exist
ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
```

So, obviously I am doing something wrong... The dump contains three tables, `first_report`,`second_report` and `relation_table`.

Answer (score 1):

1. you definitely  don't need to create empty tables in PostgreSQL, your dump file should contains `create table` statements. I'd recommend to test with dumping a schema only, without data `sqlite3 sqlite.db .schema > dump.sql`
2. In order to restore db from dump inside a container just run

   `kubectl exec -it postgres-pod -- psql --username admin --d testdb < dump.sql`

If it won't help, please share you **dump.sql** file (schema only)